# MFC ID_ vs IDM_ prefixes and their range

Tags: menu, mfc, resources

I have been working on cleaning an old project's resource.h.

In the project I am working on, I have some IDs which are in the form:
`IDM_XXXX          32771`
but are referred in code in `ON_COMMAND` and `ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI` statements.

So am I right in thinking that they are following the command architecture and ideally should be named as `ID_XXX` instead of `IDM_XXXX`?

I have read through [TN022: Standard Commands Implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/11861byt%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and see that Microsoft says:

> We recommend you use the standard "IDM_" prefix for menu items which
>   do not follow the command architecture and need menu-specific code to
>   enable and disable them.

I am not sure what is meant by `menu-specific code` here.

How are `IDM_XXXX` resources normally handled? Also what is the valid range range for `IDM_XXXX`? I have gone through [TN020: ID Naming and Numbering Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2zechd4%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) but am confused.

Answer (score 0):

ID_ and IDM_ are interchangeable because commands are accessible via command bars, menus or maybe ribbons. I never use IDM_, I only use ID_

Reserved by the MFC is  0xE000->0xEFFF and 0x7000->0x7FFF.

TN020 says that menu/command IDs must be in the range of 0x8000 and greater, but I found no reason why to do this. In the tooltip handling and command routing of the dialogs of the 16bit MFC version and AFAIK an old MFC4.x version, there was a specific code that looks for commands being greater than 0x8000.

By accident I had cases were an ID <0x8000 was created, but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I would resist not following the recommendations in the technical note.  Microsoft does have undocumented messages that may interfere with your code if you violate their recommendations.  And, debugging such an issue would be difficult.  Additionally, following the recommendation allows you the extra benefit of...

> following the MFC command architecture not only makes command handlers
>   more powerful (since they will work with toolbars) but makes the
>   command handler code reusable

This means MFC will use the same code to handle any menu and toolbar interactions that are linked together.